# VM import on AWS gave me 'ClientError: Boot disk is not using MBR partitioning.' error

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

After a 10hours upload to AWS S3, I've tried to import the vm using this command

`aws ec2 import-image --description "My server VM" --disk-containers "file://C:\import\containers.json"`

but I got this while processing the VM to import it to AWS

```
{
    "ImportImageTasks": [
        {
            "Description": "myownVM",
            "ImportTaskId": "import-ami-guid",
            "Platform": "Windows",
            "SnapshotDetails": [
                {
                    "DiskImageSize": 28333778432.0,
                    "Format": "VMDK",
                    "Status": "completed",
                    "UserBucket": {
                        "S3Bucket": "my",
                        "S3Key": "Windows 10 x64.ova"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "Status": "deleted",
            "StatusMessage": "ClientError: Boot disk is not using MBR partitioning.",
            "Tags": []
        }
    ]
}
```

It was created with VMWare 16 Professional, then exported it to ova... what have I done wrong?
I've tried googling it but I've seen no error corresponding to this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The Windows 10 boot disk is probably formatted with GPT and not MBR, which is not supported for VMDK disk images.

From the VMIE docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmie_prereqs.html#limitations-image

> UEFI/EFI boot partitions are supported only for Windows boot volumes with VHDX as the image format. Otherwise, a VM's boot volume must use Master Boot Record (MBR) partitions.

You can check using the command, from inside the VM:

```
diskpart
list disk
```

If it shows an asterisk in the GPT column, it's using GPT. If not, it's using MBR.

https://www.top-password.com/blog/tag/how-to-check-gpt-or-mbr-windows-10 has screenshots if you'd like to check via a GUI.

I'm not aware of any way to convert from GPT to MBR without wiping the drive and reinstalling Windows.

If you do reinstall, make sure you disable UEFI and secure boot if you have those options in the VM BIOS in VMware Workstation. That should allow you to choose the "custom" install during the Windows setup and then delete the default partitions and recreate them, as described here:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install-winpc/why-the-latest-w10-cant-install-mbr-disk/04351813-f7f5-46b8-b045-7d3b43094d36

Another option would be to use VHD(x) disk images using VirtualBox instead of VMware Workstation. Theoretically, this should allow you to continue using GPT. A walkthrough for this route is here:
https://gist.github.com/peterforgacs/abebc777fcd6f4b67c07b2283cd31777